# setInterval no me actualiza el estado de un componente React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, setinterval, useeffect

tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy intentando crear un componente en React cuya funcion es cargar 5 urls de una API para luego mediante un setINterval cambiar, cada 5 segundos, la url de la imagen que se renderiza, para así tener una imagen que cambia cada cierto tiempo. El componente tambien tiene dos botones para retroceder o pasar a la siguiente imagen.

La logica que implemento es tener 3 estados, la primera es un array que contiene 6 array con la informacion necesaria de 6 imagenes(url y title); el otro estado contiene una url y un titulo; finalmente el estado index es un numero que me ayuda a acceder a uno de los 6 array del primer estado y a actualizar el segundo estado con dicho array.

```
function DiscountSection() {
    const [imagesProductsDiscount, setImagesProductsDiscount] = React.useState(
        []
    );
    const [imgInfo, setImgInfo] = React.useState([]);
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
```

Luego tengo una funcion que me ayuda a aumentar o disminuir el index y a actualizar el segundo estado. Dicha funcion recibe un parametro que me indica si quiero aumentar o disminuir el index (esta funcionalidad se debe a que es la misma funcion que utilizan los botones para avanzar o retroceder de imagen). La logica que implementa es verificar que el index no se pase de 5 o de 0.

```
function cambiarIndex(accion) {
        if (accion === 'SUMAR') {
            index >= 5 ? setIndex(0) : setIndex(index + 1);
        } else if (accion === 'RESTAR') {
            console.log('dentro de restar');

            index <= 0 ? setIndex(5) : setIndex(index - 1);
        }
        setImgInfo([
            imagesProductsDiscount[index][0],
            imagesProductsDiscount[index][1],
        ]);
    }
```

Luego uso dos useEffect, uno para cargar la informacion de la API y para actualizar el primer estado.
El segundo estado me ayuda a implementar el setInterval y a eliminarlo cuando el componente se desmonta

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        async function cargarImagenesDescuento() {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const res = await fetch(
                    'https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products?offset=0&limit=6'
                );
                const data = await res.json();

                const imagesInfo = [];
                data.map((imageObject) => {
                    const imageUrl = imageObject['images'][0];
                    const title = imageObject['title'];
                    if (imageUrl !== '') {
                        imagesInfo.push([imageUrl, title]);
                    }
                });
                setImagesProductsDiscount(imagesInfo);
            } catch (error) {
                    //manejo del error
            }
        }
        cargarImagenesDescuento();
    }, []);

    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const idSetInterval = setInterval(() => {
            cambiarIndex('SUMAR');
        }, 5000);
        return () => clearInterval(idSetInterval);
    }, [imagesProductsDiscount]);
```

Finalmete el renderizado del componente, por una parte, verifica si ya se cargo el primer estado y si el segundo estado no esta vacio; por otra parte, implementa dos botones que, mediante el evento onClick llaman a la funcion de cambiarIndex(), uno lo disminuye y el otro lo aumenta.

```
    return (
        <article className='discountSection'>
            
            {!!imagesProductsDiscount && imgInfo != [] && (
                <img src={imgInfo[0]} alt={imgInfo[1]} />
            )}
            <div className='btnChangeImgContainer'>
                <button
                    className='btnChangeImg'
                    onClick={() => {
                        cambiarIndex('RESTAR');
                    }}>
                    &#8606;
                </button>
                <button
                    className='btnChangeImg'
                    onClick={() => {
                        cambiarIndex('SUMAR');
                    }}>
                    &#8608;
                </button>
            </div>
        </article>
    );
}
```

Ahora si el problema que me ocurre:
Cuando uso los botones si me cambia las imagenes y aunque el setInterval se ejecuta, no aumenta el index. Antes de poner el index en un estado implementaba la logica de aumentar dentro del setInterval, con una variable dentro del useEffect, y si me cambiaba el index y la imagen automaticamente. La verdad no se que me estoy perdiendo del funcionamiento del setInterval pero ya intente buscar documentacion y no  he podido encontrar nada.

Les agredezo si me pueden ayudar a decir que esta mal implementado o que no estoy entendiendo.
Gracias y perdon si la pregunta quedo demasiado larga.